# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState (EditText focus change)

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception, ondestroy

I have ActivityA attaching FragmentA. There's an EditText in FragmentA which, if focused, adds FragmentB (below). The stack trace starts with `onDestroy` in ActivityA, which triggers `onFocusChange`, which fires off `popBackStack`. The `isRemovingOrPartOfRemovalChain()` should be returning true at this point but it occasionally returns false causing the `popBackStack`, hence the exception. Is there a bug in that method?

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

                Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_B);

                if(fragment == null){
                    FragmentB fragmentB = FragmentB.newInstance();

                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_b, fragmentB, FRAGMENT_B);
                    fragmentExploreSearchListTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentExploreSearchListTransaction.commit();
            }
            else{
                if(!isRemovingOrPartOfRemovalChain()){
                    getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }

            }
        }

    });

public boolean isRemovingOrPartOfRemovalChain(){

    if(isRemoving()){
        return true;
    }

    Fragment fragment = this.getParentFragment();

    if(fragment != null){
        if(((MainFragment) fragment).isRemovingOrPartOfRemovalChain()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    else{
        return(getActivity().isFinishing());
    }

}

/**
 * Return true if this fragment is currently being removed from its
 * activity.  This is  <em>not</em> whether its activity is finishing, but
 * rather whether it is in the process of being removed from its activity.
 */
final public boolean isRemoving() {
    return mRemoving;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the `isRemoving()` method's implementation?

Comment: @GeorgeD `isRemoving()` is in the Android Fragment class. I added it to the bottom of the post.

Comment: Why not simply tag the back stack action and then use [findFragmentByTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29)? This way you can be 100% sure the fragment is still in the stack.

Comment: @ono `getActivity().isFinishing()` should be an independent check, just like `if(isRemoving())`. It should also be the _very first_ check.

Comment: @Athena so something like `if(getActivity().isFinishing || isRemoving()) ( return true; }` ?

Comment: @ono yes, that looks right.

Answer (score 1):

When you commit fragment after `onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outState)` callback (e.g. `onDestroy()`), the committable Fragment state will be lost (becase `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` won't be called in this situation).

In this case, when `Activity` is recreated, the committed fragment will  not be present in `Activity's` `FragmentManager`,  and so will not be restored. This is considered a **state loss**.

This behaviour might break or corrupt user experience, and is considered unintentional and exceptional, so the Android framework warns you about that by throwing an exception :-) Better save than sorry, right?

In case one knows what one's doing (which is almost always not so :-)), one may stick with `.commitAllowingStateLoss()`, but I strongly advise against it, as it will bring a legal bughole into your application.

Just do not commit fragments after it has became known that your Activity is destroying: for example,

```
...

boolean fieldActivityIsDestroying;

....

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(out);
    fieldActivityIsDestroying = true;
}
```

and check for field value when commiting the fragment.

Also you might want to `FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()` to perform any fragment transactions immediately after you commit them to manager (default commit is asynchronous).

Answer (score 0):

your issue because of activity state lost.

try this
`fragmentExploreSearchListTransaction.commit()`

to

```
fragmentExploreSearchListTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

but it is not good solution, [so i refer you read this blog](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html), this blog is about fragment Transaction after save Activity Instance, I hope my information will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough code to provide with the complete solution, but in this case:

1. It's better use [Fragment#isRemoving()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isRemoving()) to check if fragment removed from activity;
2. If focus changed expected from user interaction with the screen it's better set/remove listener at following methods:

   - onCreateView()/onDestroyView();
   - onResume()/onPause();

If there is any reason that this solutions not work feel free to clarify.
Good luck!

Comment: When I check `!isRemoving()` and call dialogFragment.show(...), an exception arises again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the onFocusedChangeListener in OnResume() and remove it in OnPause()?
That should prevent it from being triggered when your activity is finishing.